# C Switch/case macros, multiple cases

Tags: c, switch-statement, c-preprocessor

(I know most people are going to say it's horrible).

I have written the following macros to easily write switchs using strings instead of if/else if/else :

```
#define str_switch( value )                                    \
do {                                                           \
    const char * __strswitchptr__ = (value);                   \
    if( 0 )                                                    \

#define str_case( test )                                       \
    } if( strcmp( __strswitchptr__, (test) ) == 0 ) {          \

#define str_default                                            \
    } else {                                                   \

#define str_switchend                                          \
} while( 0 );                                                  \
```

Which i am using this way :

```
char * sVal =  "D";

str_switch( sVal )
{
str_case( "A" )
    printf( "Case A" );
    break;
str_case( "B" )
    printf( "Case B" );
    break;
str_case( "C" )
    printf( "Case C" );
    break;
str_default
    printf( "Error" );
}
str_switchend
```

But i can't figure out how i could modify it so i could use multiple cases :

```
char * sVal =  "D";

str_switch( sVal )
{
str_case( "A" )
    printf( "Case A" );
    break;
str_case( "B" )
    printf( "Case B" );
    break;
str_case( "C" )
str_case( "D" )
str_case( "E" )
    printf( "Case C" );
    break;
str_default
    printf( "Error" );
}
str_switchend
```

Any idea ? Thanks :-)

Comment: because switch does only integer comparisons

Comment: As far as i know you can't compare strings using C switch.

Comment: @OliverMatthews Ohh..., well you could make a function that would spit out integers.

Comment: Just a sidenote: `__strswitchptr__` is reserved by the standard. You can use `_strswitchptr` which is reserved for identifiers in _file_ scope, so you can be sure it won't get accidentally replaced by a macro or something in a header or cause other problems.

Comment: Ho well i actually used this long and unprobable name to avoid name clashes, and it appears it's a standard one... :o

Comment: By the way, this may be slightly misleading. For example this switch case doesn't have the "fall-through" behavior and in fact the `break`s are unnecessary. You might want to think about that too!

Comment: @Shahbaz it seems that if he takes SergeyL's solution, the "fall-through" will be working as one would expect.

Comment: The macro defines a loop so i don't understand why you are saying that a break wold cause a problem. Using a break should, as far as i understand, immediatly leave the do while loop. What do you mean by fall-trhough ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?
When one case evaluates to true it will continue through all if's until a `break` is encountered:

```
#define str_switch( value )                                    \
do {                                                           \
    const char * __strswitchptr__ = (value);                   \
    int __previous_case_true = 0;                              \
    if( 0 )                                                    \

#define str_case( test )                                       \
    } if(  __previous_case_true                                \
        || strcmp( __strswitchptr__, (test) ) == 0 ) {         \
        __previous_case_true = 1;                              \

#define str_default                                            \
    } {                                                        \

#define str_switchend                                          \
} while( 0 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's smart. Is there a if-nesting limit on compilers ? A long list of cases could maybe cause a problem ?

Comment: @Virus721 The if's are not nested. They are sequential.

Comment: Next challenge: write a `str_goto(string)` that would jump to `str_case(string)`. Then you'd have a complete `switch` implementation!

Comment: @Shahbaz urgh, [no `goto`s](http://xkcd.com/292/)! Though it might be possible if you could use something like an inverse for the `#` (stringify) macro operator to form labels out of the `test`s and prepend them to the `if`s.

Comment: gotos would be a problem in case of multiple switches in the same function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch instead:

```
char * sVal =  "D";

while ( *sVal ) {
    switch ( *sVal ) {
        case 'A':
            printf( "Case A" );
        break;

        case 'B':
            printf( "Case B" );
        break;

        case 'C':
        case 'D':
        case 'E':
            printf( "Case C" );
        break;

        default:
            printf( "Error" );

    }
    sVal++;
}
```